# Flutter Hot Reload issue

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, android-sdk-tools

i have a flutter app, i have been working on it before with no issues on hot reload , suddenly when i save my changes on vsCode it did trigger the hot reload but the changes not applied to the emulator

i have vsCode

[image: version]

with the following  flutter ver
[image]

Comment: are you aware of hot reload [limitations](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/hot-reload#limitations)? if it is not a case i would override `State.reassemble` method in some of your widgets and check if its called

Comment: @pskink hot restart worked with delay, but before it was working with hot reload? what has changed ?

Comment: @pskink where i can find that ?